# App crashing when switching to landscape mode (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm new to android development, and I have been trying to use fragments, however, the app is crashing when I try to switch to landscape mode. I have been trying to use `android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in my application manifest, but it seems that the application just ignores it and keeps staying in portrait mode despite being in landscape until the app restarts.

Here is my code 
main XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.example.TopFrag"
        android:layout_width="421dp"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.49"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.BottomFrag"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="568dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.708"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    //Main activity `

       package com.example;
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import android.app.Fragment;
       import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
       import android.app.FragmentManager;

       import android.os.Bundle;
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TopFrag.TopHalfFragmentListener{




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        Fragment myFragment = new TopFrag();

        ft.replace(R.id.fragment,myFragment);

        ft.commit();
      }

    @Override
      public void handleClicks(int holder) {

       }
     }
```

Fragment XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/topFrag"
    tools:context=".TopFrag" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="71dp"
            android:text="@string/minus"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDown"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.855"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="88dp"
            android:text="@string/plus"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Fragment.java

```
     package com.example;


     import android.os.Bundle;

     import android.app.Fragment;

     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.Button;


       /**
       * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
      */
         public class TopFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{


      public TopFrag() {
         // Required empty public constructor
      }
     Button up;
     Button down;
     int count =0;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false);

        up = mv.findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        down = mv.findViewById(R.id.btnUp);

        up.setOnClickListener(this);
        down.setOnClickListener(this);

        return mv;
    }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (up.isPressed()){
            count= count+1;
         }else if(count>0){
            count= count -1;
         }

         TopHalfFragmentListener clickListner = (TopHalfFragmentListener) getActivity();
         clickListner.handleClicks(count);
       }

     public interface TopHalfFragmentListener{
        void handleClicks(int count);
      }
     }
```

Fragment 2 XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bottomFragColor"
    tools:context=".BottomFrag" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOutput"
            android:layout_width="31dp"
            android:layout_height="13dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Fragment 2.JAVA

```
     import android.os.Bundle;

     import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;


       /**
        * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
       */
       public class BottomFrag extends Fragment {


      public BottomFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
      }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View mv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom, container, false);

        return mv;
       }

     }
```

The error i received..

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example, PID: 1096
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file 
    line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4754)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1599)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error 
     inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.TopFrag did not create a view.
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3643)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4754)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1599)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see no view with  id R.id.fragment_top. Where is that?

Comment: can you show me your manifest.xml file